# Adding entity with relationship to existing entity in jhipster

Tags: spring, code-generation, jhipster

I have an Jhipster app with an existing entity `Company`.
Now I want to add an Entity `Vehicle` and created an "vehicle.jh" file for the generator, like this:

```
entity Vehicle {
    name String
    category String 
    // ...
}
relationship OneToMany {
    Company{vehicles} to Vehicle{owner}
}
```

On the first try, the generator complained it does not know about "Company".
I then tried to add it an empty declaration, like this

```
entity Company
```

But this overwrites the existing Company-entity classes and removes the existing fields in them.

Is it possible to generate a new entity and connects it with the existing entities, if yes, how? Or should I redoing the steps done the generator by hand, or (or use git to merge them somehow with the original source files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JHipster requires that all your entities are defined in one single JDL file. If you haven't saved the definition of your previous entities you can export them using `jhipster export-jdl app.jh` then edit app.jh to add your new entity and re-import using `jhipster import-jdl app.jh`